# How to select text - string from one XML element

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to choose string from XML element **Address**

Here is my XML file

```
<table>
    <row>
        <address>Greenwich Avenue 20, New York</address>
    </row>
</table>
```

Here is my XSLT file

```
<xsl:for-each select="table/row">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="address"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here is my wished output

```
Greenwich Avenue
```

Or

```
New York
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you really mean "Greenwich Avenue" in your wished output, and not "Greenwich Avenue 20"?

Comment: Just ,,Greenwich Avenue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation shows how to produce either of the two strings**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="address">
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "translate(substring-before(., ','),
                 '01234567890', ''
                 )
      "/>
    =============
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ',')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<table>
    <row>
        <address>Greenwich Avenue 20, New York</address>
    </row>
</table>
```

**the wanted two strings are obtained as the result of evaluating specific XPath expressions -- then output**:

```
Greenwich Avenue 
=============
New York
```